# Any Elegant Ideas on how to parse this Dataset?

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I'm using PHP 5.3 to receive a Dataset from a web service call that brings back information on one or many transactions.  Each transaction's return values are delimited by a pipe (`|`), and beginning/ending of a transaction is delimited by a space.

```
2109695|49658|25446|4|NSF|2010-11-24 13:34:00Z 2110314|45276|26311|4|NSF|2010-11-24 13:34:00Z 2110311|52117|26308|4|NSF|2010-11-24 13:34:00Z (etc)
```

Doing a simple split on space doesn't work because of the space in the datetime stamp.  I know regex well enough to know that there are always different ways to break this down, so I thought getting a few expert opinions would help me come up with the most airtight regex.

Comment: Could you not just split it by "Z "?

Comment: Yeah, I think you have two problems now.  explode on 'Z' me thinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If each timestamp is going to have a `Z` at the end you can use positive lookbehind assertion to split on space only if it's preceded by a `Z` as:

```
$transaction = preg_split('/(?<=Z) /',$input);
```

Once you get the transactions, you can split them on `|` to get the individual parts.

[**Codepad link**](http://codepad.org/YzBei3Fa)

Note that if your data has a `Z` followed a space anywhere else other than the timestamp, the above logic will fail. To overcome than you can split on space only if it's preceded by a timestamp pattern as:

```
$transaction = preg_split('/(?<=\d\d:\d\d:\d\dZ) /',$input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode('|', $data)` function

Answer (score 1):

Each timestamp is going to have a Z at the end so explode it by 'Z '. You don't need a regular expression. There's no chance that the date has a Z after it only the time.

[example](http://ideone.com/pA5XO)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, if you know for sure that there will be no `Z` characters anywhere other than in the date, you could just do:

```
$records = explode('Z', $data);
```

But if you have them elsewhere, you'll need to do something a bit fancier.

```
$regex = '#(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}Z)\s#i';
$records = preg_split($regex, $data, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Basically, that record looks for the time portion (`00:00:00`) followed by a `Z`.  Then it splits on the following white-space character...